# Intersection of stabilisers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I have a short question: if $G$ acts on $X$, is the intersection of all the stabilisers the same as the conjugates of the stabilisers? In other words does, for any $z\in X:$

$$\bigcap_{g\in G} g\,\text{stab}(z)\,g^{-1}=\bigcap_{x\in X} \text{stab}(x)?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not the case.
As a counterexample, consider any action such that $G$ fixes some point of $X$ but acts non-trivially on another.

If the action of $G$ is transitive, however, then your statement is true, for in this case  all point stabilizers are conjugate to each other.
Try showing that
$$
\operatorname{stab}(g\cdot x) = g \operatorname{stab}(x) g^{-1}.
$$